# How to test multilple subscription in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, jasmine, angular-unit-test

In my Angular Unit Test I want to check whether `myComponent.items$` have 0 results when I call subject `myComponent.clearInput$.next()`. Before that I want to ensure that there are some records. `myComponent.items$` can be populated by `myComponent.nameInput$.next("test")`.

Unfortunately both subscription are triggered after both Subjects have been called, so `myComponent.items$` is always 0.

```
it("when control touched then clear input value", done => {

    myComponent.items$.pipe(first()).subscribe(result => {
        expect(result.length).toBe(2); 
        // it's always 0 because of myComponent.clearInput$.next(); from last line
    })
    myComponent.nameInput$.next("test");

// Now should wait after code from above will finish then the rest should be executed after that.

    myComponent.items$.pipe(first()).subscribe(result => {
        expect(result.length).toBe(0);
        done(); // test should be finished here
    })
    myComponent.clearInput$.next();
});
```

---

This is how is items$ is called by those Subjects

```
this.items$ = merge(
    this.nameInput$.pipe(
        switchMap((name: string) =>
            iif(() => this._partyType === "PT",
                this.someService.getByName(name),
                this.otherService.getByOtherName(name)
            )
        )
    ),
    this.clearInput$.pipe(
        switchMapTo(of([]))
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

In my unit tests, I rarely `subscribe`. I use `promise` approach because then I can wait.

Try this:

```
it("when control touched then clear input value", async done => {
   myComponent.nameInput$.next("test");
   console.log('first await...');
   const result = await myComponent.items$.pipe(take(1)).toPromise();
   console.log('after first await...');
   expect(result.length).toBe(2);

   myComponent.clearInput$.next();
   console.log('second await...');
   const newResult = await myComponent.items$.pipe(take(1)).toPromise();
   console.log('after second await...');
   expect(newResult.length).toBe(0);
   done();
});
```

I think that's what you want. This way we can have blocking code and much better assertions.

Comment: I have an error: Error: Timeout - Async function did not complete within 5000ms (set by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL)

Comment: Okay, the test is getting stuck on a `Promise`. Make sure the test is structured well and the component as well. I added `console.logs`, see which `after ...` log you don't see and that's the promise that has never been resolved.

Comment: `console.log('after first await...');` is never triggered

Comment: That means `items$` does not trigger. How are `nameInput$` and `items$` related?

Comment: I think it's because `nameInput$` is a Subject (not ReplaySubject) so doesn't have any cached value when we call `toPromise()`

Comment: Can you show your component code and how `nameInput$` and `items$` are related? Where basically when `nameInput$` emits, `items$` emits as well?

Comment: Updated answer. When I changed it to `ReplaySubject` it worked but this is isn't good solution for me.

Comment: What is `iif(() => this._partyType === "PT",
                this.someService.getByName(name),
                this.otherService.getByOtherName(name)
            )`, I bet this is causing the issue. When it goes into the `switchMap`, does the `switchMap` return an observable?

Comment: Even if I will remove this and replace with just `this.otherService.getByOtherName(name)` in switchMap - still doesn't work. Service working fine (I checked with console.log inside)